# Difference between random variable and probability

Tags: probability

We have tickets with numbers form $1$ to $20$. We take randomly 3 tickets. We bet that at least one of the tickets will be of number bigger or equal to $17$. What is the probability that we win the bet?

My try:
I look at it to be the same as if we would have 4 white balls and 16 black balls and we take randomly 3, what would be the probability that one of those $3$ is white.
$$\frac{\binom{4}{1}+ \binom{16}{1}\binom{4}{1}+\binom{16}{1}\binom{15}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{20}{3}} = \text{not correct result}$$

The correct result is that we take $$P\{x = i\}=\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{i-1}{2}}{\binom{20}{3}}$$

And then we sum it up for $i = 17,18,19,20$

We get a result that is close to one half.

However what is the difference between both procedures? Why do we get different results?

Comment: @DonThousand I see I got it completely wrong. I should have done what tommik did in his answer

Comment: I think you need to choose a more accurate title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my opinion an equivalent correct result is

$$\frac{\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{16}{2}+\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{16}{1}+\binom{4}{3}\cdot\binom{16}{0}}{\binom{20}{3}}=1-\frac{\binom{16}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}}=\frac{29}{57}$$

and this expression is self explicative

Comment: Yes I should have done this, I got it wrong in the first example

Comment: Same as $1$ minus prob. all 16 or less, $1-[\binom{16}{3}/\binom{20}{3}]=29/57.$

Comment: @VLC : my expression gives  the same result as the one you showed as correct. Same result as the other answers gave: $29/57$

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is right but your calculation is wrong, as others have noted. However ... why not simplify and just say - let's calculate the probability to *lose* the bet. In other words, that your choice of $4$ balls out of $20$ ends up being all within the $16$ black balls. The result is:

$$\frac{16\choose 3}{20\choose 3}=\frac{16\cdot 15\cdot 14}{20\cdot 19\cdot 18}=\frac{28}{57}$$

and so the probability you are after is $1-\frac{28}{57}=\frac{29}{57}$